# django using ajax to call backend has problem

Tags: javascript, django, ajax, csrf-token

I'm new to Django. I want to create liking icon for my blog post. here is a heart icon in my html file, and I want when I click it, it turns to red and then calls a function in backend to change a number in database and send back the new number to the template, all using Ajax, in order not to refreshing the page after liking the post. What should I do, and where is the problem?

In html file:

```
  <i class="fas fa-heart"></i>
  <b>{{ note.like }}</b>
```

The script part:

```
  <script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('.fa-heart').click(function(e){
            this.style.color = this.style.color == 'red' ? 'white' : 'red';
            e.preventDefault();

                $.ajax({
                    type:'POST',
                    url:"vote/like/",
                    data:{
                        num:"niloofar",
                        //I think the problem is with this csrf token part
                        csrfmiddlewaretoken:$('input[name=csrfmiddlewaretoken]').val(),
                    },
                    success: function(data){
                        alert(data);
                    },
                    error : function() {
                        console.log("Error");
                    }
                });
        });
    });
  </script>
```

In views:

```
  def like(request):
      if request.method == 'POST':
        print(request.POST)
        return HttpResponse('done')
```

In urls.py:

```
  path('<int:id>/vote/like/', views.like, name='like'),
```

And the error is:

> Internal Server Error: /notes/1/vote/like/ Traceback (most recent call
> last):   File
> "/home/niloofar/git/djangoenv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py",
> line 47, in inner
> response = get_response(request)   File "/home/niloofar/git/djangoenv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py",
> line 181, in _get_response
> response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs) TypeError: like() got an unexpected keyword argument 'id'

Comment: Have you setup the `vote/like/` endpoint in your `urls.py`?

Comment: @stackdon yes. I have updated the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A request to `/1/vote/like/` would match the URL `<int:id>/vote/like/` in the list and Django would call the function `views.like(request, id=1)` but your function only accept single argument which is `request` hence the error.

Change your function `like` to something like below then it should work fine.

```
def like(request, id):
    ...
```

OR

```
def like(request, *args, **kwargs):
    ...
```

Comment: Oh you're right! Why I didn't notice that! Thank you.